# C# Executing console command

Tags: c#, console

Okey, so I want my C# program execute two following console commands.

```
takeown /f "c:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe"  
icacls "c:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe" /grant administrators:F
```

My problem is that C# cannot handle additional "s in path. (also tried to use escape sequences with no luck)

Comment: "My problem is that C# cannot handle additional "s in path" - how do you mean? And can you explain [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and post your current code, explaining where you are stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you have problems with the `"` embedded in the command line parameters, you simply need to escape them:

```
Process.Start("takeown", @"/f ""c:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe""");
Process.Start("icacls", 
              @"""c:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe"" /grant administrators:F");
```

I have used verbatim string literals (those that start with `@`) to avoid having to escape the `\` in the paths as I would need to do with other string literals.

Comment: second line was giving me "program cannot be found" so i removed the space at "icacls " and its working perfectly.